# ID missing from one table, include it in the results anyway

Tags: mysql, sql

In my mySQL database I have two tables called job_details and job_actions. In the job_details table, if I get the Detail_ID for Job_ID 41230, then I get five results. For example:

```
select Detail_ID from job_details where Job_ID = '41230';
```

[image]

What I want to do is use the same Job_ID to get the Percent_Complete for each Detail_ID from the job_actions table. For example, this yields only 4 records because not all of the Detail_IDs appear in this table:

```
select Detail_ID, Percent_Complete from job_actions where Job_ID = '41230';
```

[image]

I get the same four records when I try to join both tables:

```
select 
    details.Detail_ID,
    actions.Percent_Complete
from 
    job_details details,
    job_actions actions
where 
    details.Job_ID = '41230' and
    details.Job_ID = actions.Job_ID and
    details.Detail_ID = actions.Detail_ID;
```

I would like my output to include EVERY Detail_ID found in the job_details table, even if it is not found in the job_actions table. For example:

[image]

I know how to find the Detail_ID that is missing from the job_actions table, but not how to include it in the results. For example:

```
select details.Detail_ID from job_details details 
left join job_actions actions using (Detail_ID) 
where actions.Detail_ID IS NULL and details.Job_ID = '41230';
```

How can I include the Detail_ID 87679 in the results even though it is missing from the job_actions table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

You simply want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select details.Detail_ID, actions.Percent_Complete
from job_details details left join
     job_actions actions
     on details.Job_ID = actions.Job_ID and
        details.Detail_ID = actions.Detail_ID
where details.Job_ID = 41230;  -- I assume Job_ID is a number so the single quotes are not necessary
```

Comment: Works great! However, you said "never use commas in the from clause." Why not?

Comment: @ChrisNielsen . . . Because the correct way to express a `JOIN` is to use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.  Implicit Cartesian products is just sloppy logic.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you have wrote the syntax of `joins` but with older style with *where* clause that could turn into actually *inner* join or *equi* join.

So, use proper explicit `join` syntax with type of `left join`

```
select jd.Detail_ID, ja.Percent_Complete 
from job_details jd left join job_actions ja on 
                    ja.Job_ID = jd.Job_ID and
                    ja.Detail_ID = jd.Detail_ID 
where jd.Job_ID = '41230';
```

You could also use `subquery` instead since you are looking for all `Detail_ID` from `job_details` table

```
select Detail_ID,
       (select Percent_Complete from job_actions 
        where Job_ID = jd.Job_ID and 
              Detail_ID = jd.Detail_ID) as Percent_Complete  -- Use limit  with order by clause in case one or more Percent found. 
from job_details jd 
where Job_ID = '41230';
```

I suspect, if you have `Job_ID` as type of *numeric* then you don't need to use of *quotes* just use *value*  (i.e. *41230*)

Comment: Great idea to use a subquery. Thanks!